# Should links to version-specific documentation be updated (if applicable)?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, documentation

I see quite a number of answers (specifically questions dealing with Qt), which link to a specific version of documentation, e.g. v4.5 of Qt. If this is appropriate, i.e. the answer refers to a version-specific feature, I have no problem with it, but I was wondering if it is appropriate to update the links to a non-version specific version (if available).

For example, in
[What unit-testing framework should I use for Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524390/qt-what-unit-testing-framework/1524400#1524400) the answer was referring to a specific version of QtTestLib Tutorial, although there was no version-specific content in the answer. I updated the link to point to the stable version.